# Is there a way to make my loggedIn variable reference my isLoggedIn variable in a statefulwidget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and I currently experimenting with how I can limit access to pages that are of limit to users who are not logged in.

router:

```
final router = GoRouter(
  redirect: (state) {
    //Need the actual value from loginpage
    final loggedIn = ;

    final isLoggingIn = state.location == '/loginpage';

    if (!loggedIn && !isLoggingIn) return '/loginpage';

    if (loggedIn && isLoggingIn) return '/menupage';

    return null;
  },
```

LoginPage:

```
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  bool isProgressing = false;
  bool isLoggedIn = false;
  String errorMessage = '';
  String? name;
  String? auth0Id;
  String? accessToken;
  String? tokenValid;}
```

Is there anyway for me to take the value of isLoggedIn from loginpage and reference it in loggedIn from router?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should learn [Shared Preference](https://medium.com/@bharathraj_e/how-to-create-singleton-shared-preference-in-flutter-flutter-web-a10aa80b7e14) for save isLogged info to phone storage.
After that you can check on router function your isLogged info.

Sample:

```
if(Prefs.isLoggedIn)
return "/loginpage"
else 
return "/menupage"
```

Comment: ```import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Preferences {
  static SharedPreferences prefs =
      SharedPreferences.getInstance() as SharedPreferences;

  static const loginStatus = 'isLoggedIn';

  static Future init() async => prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  static Future setLoginStatus(bool isLoggedIn) async =>
      await prefs.setBool(loginStatus, isLoggedIn);

  static bool? getLoginStatus() => prefs.getBool(loginStatus);
}```

 I have implemented this, but end up with my app going in an endless loop. Any tips?

Comment: I tried to format it, but it didnt work very well. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You Should use [Shared Preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) plugin to achieve this functionality
for example :

```
void isLoggedIn() async {
  var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  if (prefs.getBool("isLoggedIn")!) {
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/menupage");
    //prefs.setBool("isLoggedIn", true);
  } else {
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/loginpage");
    //prefs.setBool("isLoggedIn", false);
  }
}
```